# swf file as hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make the swf file to act as an hyperlink i tried adding ,doesnt seem to work

```
    <a><OBJECT
                                 classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
                                 WIDTH="50"
                                 HEIGHT="50"
                                 id="myMovieName">

                               <PARAM NAME="movie" VALUE="/media/players/testsound.swf" />
                               <PARAM NAME="quality" VALUE="high" />
                               <PARAM NAME="bgcolor" VALUE="#FFFFFF" />

                               <EMBED
                                  href="/media/players/testsound.swf"
         src="/media/players/testsound.swf"
         flashvars="soundUrl=sound.mp3"
                                  quality=high
                                  bgcolor=#FFFFFF
                                  NAME="myMovieName"
                                  ALIGN=""
                                  TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash">
                               </EMBED>
                               </OBJECT></a>
```

Comment: you missed the `href` in the `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onclick="location.href='http://google.com/';" style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;">
```